# Making current active website page not reload in navbar

Tags: php, html

I'll start off with saying that I am brand new to PhP, but am trying to use it to set load my header from 1 file into all of my website pages. I have successfully accomplished this and with that have also been able to set a .active class to whichever page is currently active.

My question is, if there is anyway I can make the active page not reload when it is clicked in the navbar out of personal preference. I have so far accomplished this by just setting the href link to "#" but I can't really do that if I am loading the same header from every file. Is there some way else I can do this possibly with PhP in my header.php file? Please let me know, be kind, again I'm brand new, here is my code...

**INDEX.PHP**

```
<html>

    <head>

        <!-- Meta & Other -->
        <title>Infamous | Home</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="description" content="Infamous official website">
        <meta name="keywords" content ="Infamous, Minecraft, Server, Game, Gaming">
        <meta name="author" content="MrWardy">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Stylesheets/header.css">

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/35fad75205.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kanit&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">



    </head>



    <body>

        <?php $page = 'home'; include('header.php'); ?>

        <!-- JavsScript -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

**APPLY.PHP**

```
<html>

    <head>

        <!-- Meta & Other -->
        <title>Infamous | Apply</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="description" content="Infamous official website">
        <meta name="keywords" content ="Infamous, Minecraft, Server, Game, Gaming, Apply, Application, Staff">
        <meta name="author" content="MrWardy">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Stylesheets/default.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Stylesheets/header.css">

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/35fad75205.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kanit&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">



    </head>



    <body>

        <?php $page = 'apply'; include('header.php'); ?>

        <!-- JavsScript -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

**HEADER.PHP**

```
            <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar-nav">
                <div class="container grid-container">
                    <a class="<?php echo ($page == 'home') ? "active" : ""; ?> navlink" href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
                    <a class="navlink" href="#rules"><i class="fas fa-book"></i> Rules</a>
                    <a class="<?php echo ($page == 'apply') ? "active" : ""; ?> navlink" href="./apply.php"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Apply</a>
                    <a class="navlink" href="#store"><i class="fas fa-tags"></i> Store</a>
                    <a class="navlink" href="https://discord.gg/ZnN3f4P" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-discord"></i> Discord</a>
                    <a class="navlink" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFvs3IZNgziCe0WARpJpYVw" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i> YouTube</a>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <img class="heading-banner mx-auto d-block" src="./Images/banner.png" alt="Infamous banner">
        </header>
```

Comment: To achieve that you will have to use javascript to disable click on the active link or update the href attribute to <a href="javascript:;">...</a>

Comment: Just don't generate a clickable link for the current page?

Comment: @andychukse how could I go about doing that? I tried googling and put something together using an if statement with `window.location.href.toLowerCase().includes('index')` to see if the user is at the page I'm looking for then using a jQuery statement I found on google to try to disable the click event, but that didn't do anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you can add many pages you want by using 
 `array('page'=>'IDENTIFIER','title'=>'TITLE','link'=>'link','icon'=>'icon')` separated by comma.

Header.php

```
<nav id="header-nav" class="navbar-nav">
   <div class="container grid-container">
<?php
$pages=array(
    array('page'=>'home','title'=>'Home','link'=>'./home.php','icon'=>'fas fa-home'),
    array('page'=>'apply','title'=>'Apply','link'=>'./apply.php','icon'=>'fa-user'),
    array('page'=>'other','title'=>'Other page','link'=>'./other_page.php','icon'=>'fa-user'),
    array('page'=>'youtube','title'=>'Watch video','link'=>'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFvs3IZNgziCe0WARpJpYVw','icon'=>'fab fa-youtube','newtarget'=>1)
);

foreach($pages as $pg){
    echo $pg['page']==$page?
    '<a class="navlink active"><i class="'.$pg['icon'].'"></i> '.$pg['title'].'</a>':
    '<a class="navlink" href="'.$pg['link'].'" '(.isset($pg['newtarget'])?' target="_blank"':'').'><i class="'.$pg['icon'].'"></i> '.$pg['title'].'</a>';
}
?>
    </div>
  </nav>
 <img class="heading-banner mx-auto d-block" src="./Images/banner.png" alt="Infamous banner" />
</header>
```

If you want you can add a cursor style to navlink class, this way, even without a href your  will have a nice cursor.

Comment: That does the trick with one exception, I don't fully understand this code as again I am very new to PhP, but the issue is it makes the active link invisible, can't see the text [example](https://i.imgur.com/qnterjZ.jpg)

Comment: Ahh never mind, I was able to fix the issue just by adding an href="#" to the active one in the php which does the trick, I don't mind if it's clickable and puts a # in the users url, no big deal, thank you!!

Comment: Okay, now hang on I do have a question related to that, how would I now make a link target="_blank" for example with the YouTube one you setup?

Comment: @MrWardy the fact that you wasn't seeing the link is due to your css styles, you have to change your style to deal with <a> tags in general. In regard of opening a new window, you can define it inside the array, my suggestion is to create a key/value pair which defines if that will open in a new window or not. I just edited the answer to fit your need. This approach I have used uses array and is very common for sites which store links on database, it's a little simulation to you. Please go to php.net and read about array, also about for/foreach iteration and you should be fine.

Comment: Ah I see now and now understand some more about PhP, I appreciate your help!